# How to add select option dropdown dynamically

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i have a problem with my dynamic select option. My problem is my select option didn't show anything, just show blank. I have tried many times and i am stuck

this is my html select option code

```
<select name="jumlahpesan" id="jumlahpesan" data-native-menu="false">
    <option value="choose-one" data-placeholder="true">Choose one... </option>
</select>
```

and this is my ajax code to get value to fill in my select option

```
$.ajax({
            url: host+'/skripsi3/phpmobile/cekjumlah.php',
            data: { "id": getacara},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data, status){
                $.each(data, function(i,item){  
                        $("#jumlahpesan").append('<option value="'+item.jumbros+'">"'+item.jumbros+'"</option>').trigger("create")
                });
            },
            error: function(){
                //output.text('There was an error loading the data.');
            }
        });
```

and for the last, this is my "cekjumlah.php"

```
<?php
session_start();
include "config.php";
$idacara=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["id"]);
$arr = array();
$result=mysql_query("select jumlahpesan from acara where    id_acara='$idacara'");
if (!empty($result))
{
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $tempjum = $row['jumlahpesan'];
        for($i=0;$i<$tempjum;$i++)
        {
            $fetchkategori[] = array
            (   
                'jumbros' => $i,

            );  
        }
    }
}

mysql_close($con);

header('Content-Type:application/json');
echo json_encode($fetchkategori);
?>
```

i want to fill my select option from my looping in "cekjumlah.php" and call my php with my ajax. Thank you

this is my Ajax Response

```
[{"jumbros":0},{"jumbros":1},{"jumbros":2}]
```

Comment: Can you please add your AJAX response in your question

Comment: parse your json data using JSON.parse(data) in your ajax success.

Comment: Also, as a way of debugging, try printing the full response from the ajax request to console - just to see what is returned.  `consle.log(data);` You should also print something inside the data loop to make sure it works.

Comment: hey guys thanks for your answer i have added my ajax response

Answer (score 0):

I can't really help you with the PHP side of things, so if there is a problem there, I can't see it.

But you seem to be using .each() incorrectly, as each is meant to iterate over a jquery selection of elements and execute a funciton for each element, whereas your seem to be trying to use it as a foreach over data

I think you have to replace that $.each with

```
for item in data{
   $("#jumlahpesan").append('<option value="'+item.jumbros+'">"'+item.jumbros+'"</option>').trigger("create")
}
```

(i'm assuming data is a JSON array, you may have to use JSON.parse(data) first judging by some of the comments on your post.